# Sails.js - creating empty models

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

This is the controller that I am using to create a new instance of my human model:

```
newh: function(req, res) {
var firstName = req.param('firstName');
var lastName = req.param('lastName');
var contact = req.param('contact');
var email = req.param('email');

var home = 'http://localhost:1337/humans';

Human.create({
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    contact: contact,
    email: email
}).done(function(err, user) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log('Could not create user. Error: ' + err);
    }else{
        res.redirect('/humans');
    }
});
```

This is the script that I am using to post the data to the controller:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var firstName = $('#first').val();
var lastName = $('#last').val();
var contact = $('#contact').val();
var email = $('#email').val();

$('#add').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/humans/new',
        data: {
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            contact: contact,
            email: email
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log('Successfully passed data.');
        }

    });
});
});
```

Whenever I post the information, the success function gets executed. Still, my controller doesn't seem to make use of that res.redirect() call and it simply generates empty instances of the human model.

What's the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Even after moving the var declarations inside of the click event, I still get an empty instance of the Human model.

Comment: 1) res.redirect() doesn't make sense when call is made througn AJAX. 
2) it doesn't matter where is your `var` declarations. 
3) please check in you chrome debugger or via `console.log()` what's the values of your vars before ajax call.

Comment: I've found a really bothersome issue. Whenever I update one of my scripts, it does not update on the layout page even if I am using the linker option (<!-- SCRIPTS -->) tags. How is this possible? It continues to use an old version of the script even if I manually updated it.

Comment: @ataman: I've figured it out ataman. Thanks a lot for the feedback! I have no problem now adding instances of that model. But how come my script remains to an old version even if I update the code?

Comment: @ataman: I found a solution to this: clearing my browser cache before trying anything on the page; now it works perfectly :)

Comment: Great:) . I just started to type long comment with my quesses, and I'm glad than I don't have to finish it anymore:)